# Nativescript modal button tap event not working

Tags: javascript, xml, typescript, nativescript

I can display my custom modal over my main.xml. It contains two buttons to add images or record audio.

My problem: I cannot make these buttons tap events to work when the modal is open and I click on them. console.log should display "add images" or "record audio".

**main-page.xml**

```
<FAB:fab row="1" tap="{{ openModal }}" icon="res://add_white" rippleColor="#f56c0a" class="fab-button" horizontalAlignment="right" />
```

**main.ts**

```
import {Observable} from 'data/observable';
import { Page } from "ui/page";

export class AssistenceViewModel extends Observable {

constructor() {
    super();
   }

public openModal() {
    console.log("fab tap");

    var modalPage = "./modal/modal-page";
    var context = "contexto";
    var fullscreen = false;

    const page = <Page>args.object.page;

    page.showModal(modalPage, context, function(){
        //code...
    }, fullscreen);
}
```

**modal-page.xml**

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo" class="page">

<StackLayout class="p-16">

    <Label text="Opções" horizontalAlignment="center" textWrap="true" />

    <Button class="btn mybtn" text="Adicionar Imagem" tap="{{ addImage }}"></Button>
    <Button class="btn mybtn" text="Gravar Áudio" tap="{{ addAudio }}"></Button>

  </StackLayout>

</Page>
```

**modal.ts**

```
import {Observable} from 'data/observable';

export class ModalViewModel extends Observable {

constructor(){
    super();
}

public addImage(){
    console.log("add images"); // it doesn't work
}

public addAudio(){
    console.log("record audio");  // it doesn't work
}

}
```

Comment: hmmm I think the tap event is wrong perhaps... try changing the `tap="{{ addImage }}"` part to  `(tap)="addImage()"`

Comment: This is for angular. I'm not using angular.

Comment: so the issue, as far as I can see it is that you have not set the page's bindingContext, and/or you do not have a corresponding code behind file. you have `main.ts`, `main-page.xml`, `modal.ts`, and `modal-page.xml`. so your files have to match first `main-page.ts` and `main-page.xml`. then treat `main-page.ts`, the code-behind file, as a module. `export function openModal():void {...` from `main-page.ts`, which will be picked up in 'main-page.xml'